# Search by exact words in a phrase using Umbraco Examine

Tags: lucene, umbraco, lucene.net

I have some `description` field per content and those are:

For `content1`:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. And the lazy dog is good.`

For `content2`:

`The lazy fog is crazy.`

Now, when I use keyword = `lazy dog`, I want to give result as `content1` and not `content2`

I tried like:

```
BaseSearchProvider searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearch"];
ISearchCriteria criteria =
            searcher.CreateSearchCriteria()
               .GroupedAnd( new List<string> { "description" }, "lazy dog") )
               .Compile();

ISearchResults result = searcher.Search( criteria );
```

But it didn't gave me desired results, it give me results: `content1` and `content2`.

What should I do in order to get as `content1` result ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default examine is compiling this query to:

```
+(+description:lazy dog)
```

and based on it it's returning the results with both: *lazy* and *dog* words.

What you want to achieve is:

```
+(+description:"lazy dog")
```

First of what you need to try is to escape the phrase. In your case it will be:

```
BaseSearchProvider searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearch"];
ISearchCriteria criteria =
            searcher.CreateSearchCriteria()
               .GroupedAnd( new List<string> { "description" }, "lazy dog".Escape()) )
               .Compile();

ISearchResults result = searcher.Search( criteria );
```

Can't test it now, but there were some problems with it in the past from what I remember. The second option and a life saver for you, may be building the search query manually and using the raw query.

```
BaseSearchProvider searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearch"];
ISearchCriteria criteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria();

var query = criteria.RawQuery("+description:\"lazy dog\"");

ISearchResults result = searcher.Search( query );
```

And it should return you correct = matched result only. Personally, I've used also some boosting of specific words to just point some results higher in the score list, but if you want to have only matched items, try above solutions and let me know if it helped you.

If you want to deal with more than one property, you can either use some fluent API methods like GroupedAnd or GroupedOr (depending of the desired behaviour of search) or build more advanced raw query.

For the first option, check **Grouped Operations** documentation: https://github.com/Shazwazza/Examine/wiki/Grouped-Operations.

For the second scenario it would be the best to analyze how it's done e.g. in **ezSearch** package (which btw. is awesome!): https://github.com/umco/umbraco-ezsearch/blob/master/Src/Our.Umbraco.ezSearch/Web/UI/Views/MacroPartials/ezSearch.cshtml.

Comment: How about multiple fields ? (instead of `description`, I want also `title`, `description`, etc.)

Comment: Depending on the scenario, you can either get more into manual creation of query or adding more properties to the list of fields (your first solution). If fluent API is blocking you with something, check how it's done in ezSearch for example, where it's contstructed manually: https://github.com/umco/umbraco-ezsearch/blob/master/Src/Our.Umbraco.ezSearch/Web/UI/Views/MacroPartials/ezSearch.cshtml.

Edit: updated my answer above! :)